# can i install and run visual studio 2008 on vista ultimate 32 bit?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-vista

i m new on vista i just want to install visual studio 2008 on vista ultimate 32 bit so can any body tell me tht visual studio 2008 will work properly on vista ultimate 32 bit? Infact i want to work on asp.net with c sharp so some one told me that IIS doesn't work properly on vista so i want to confirm that it is work properly or not?

please advice me soon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it will work just fine.  IIS works fine on Vista as well.  Why would you think otherwise?  Do you have specific concerns?

Comment: what you mean by "why would you think otherwise?"

Comment: I mean, why would you think Microsoft's flagship developer tool wouldn't work on its flagship OS?

Comment: e probably means: Why wouldn't it work on Vista? (It is both MS software, so rest assured they are doing everything possible to make it work well together) 

And yes. It works well together. I'm using it as my primary work environment.

Comment: i know what u said jeff but just want to confirm infact i purchased a new notebook pc in which vista home premium installed so my main concern is that it will work on vista home premium also ?? and also the main reason for asking above question because i m new on vista.

Comment: Absolutely.  That's the configuration I'm running on right now.

Comment: I use VS2005 on Vista, but only because I haven't gotten around to buying 2008 (I work at a start-up that is attempting to minimize costs).

Comment: VS2008 on both Vista x86 and Vista x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 0):

[Visual Studio on Windows Vista](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vstudio/aa948853.aspx) doesnt actually cover VS 2008 specifically but I believe it would be ok to assume that if VS 2005 was supported then VS 2008 would be to.

Answer (score 0):

it may got problem over 64 bit version of vista,but 32 bit vista genrally works lots of programs that work on XP

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I would consider Visual Studio 2008 on Vista 32bit the MOST supported configuration.  Vista was the release platform for VS2008, and it is natively a 32 bit app.  It runs under WOW emulation on 64 bit windows.